# Simplifying an algebraic equation

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry

I stumbled across this specific question where there was a fractional equation and I did not know whether I should simplify it through canceling out the terms or not. However, I decided not to. Ultimately this gave another answer, which was not meant to be given, according the the book.
I was wondering whether you should always simplify or not.

The question:
Solve: $$ \frac{1+\cos(x)}{(1+\cos(x))^2} = \frac{2}{3}$$

Solving for $x$, there should be two points, between $0$ and $2\pi$.

The answers given were $\frac{\pi}{3}$ and $\frac{5\pi}{3}$ (from my memory), and without simplifying,the additional answer was $\pi$.

Thank you

Gurjinder

---

Comment: Without simplifying, $\pi$ definitely isn't an answer. Look at your denominator.

Comment: Ahh, okay, thanks, what I did was multiply both sides by the denominators, I may have made an error with the working,

Comment: Thank you for the assistance.

Comment: You should wind up with solving $\cos(x)=\frac{1}{2}$ if the equation is what I think you mean it to be.

Comment: yeah, that was it, but how did I end up with pi as and answer?

Comment: sorry, for the open question, thank you for the help though, it would have taken me a little while to spot that it could not be pi,

Comment: I think I know what you did... instead of saying $\frac{1+\cos(x)}{(1+\cos(x))^2}=\frac{1}{1+\cos(x)}$ you multiplied both sides by $(1+\cos(x))^2$... Either way... You still have to make sure your solutions fit into your original equation.

Comment: @Gurjinder - you got $\pi$ for an answer because you multiplied the equation by $(1 + \cos x)^2$ which is $0$ when $x = \pi$. By doing so, you introduced an additional solution that was not there in the original.

Comment: Yeah, that was it, I would normally have simplified, but instead I chose to experiment, and I thought I would end up with the same answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cancelling $$1+\cos(x)\ne 0$$ we obtain by crsoo multiplication $$\cos(x)=\frac{1}{2}$$. Does this help you?

Comment: yes, thank you for the clarification and for the rest of the feedback given, by everybody else.